# How can I query a specific date in mongodb laravel, I need all data of that date

Tags: mongodb, laravel-5

I m using Moloquent for mongoDB in my project, my dates is stored in `2015-09-28 03:30:00` format in mongoDB and want to write a query like

```
select * from table where date(storeddate)='2015-09-28'
```

and

```
select * from table where year(storeddate)='2015'
```

in mongoDB with Moloquent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the query builder to take advantage of native MongoDate objects in constructing a date range that you can then use in the query. For example, the following query

```
select * from users where date(storeddate)='2015-09-28'
```

can be written as

```
$start = new MongoDate(strtotime("2015-09-28 00:00:00"));
$end = new MongoDate(strtotime("2015-09-29 00:00:00"));

$users = DB::collection('users')->whereBetween('storeddate', array($start, $end))->get();
```

---

Eloquent also supports [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/) or DateTime objects instead of MongoDate objects which will be converted internally to MongoDate objects when saved to the database.

Using the same example as above, if you want to query for records from Users data where a mongodb datetime field `storeddate` year part is 2015

```
select * from users where year(storeddate)='2015'
```

use Carbon's [**`createFromDate()`**](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/blob/master/tests/Carbon/CreateFromDateTest.php) property to create the date range that spans a year:

```
 $users = User::whereBetween(
             'storeddate', array(
                 Carbon::createFromDate(2015, 1, 1),
                 Carbon::createFromDate(2015, 12, 31)
             )
         )->get();
```